# Python - split string into multiples columns

Tags: python, string, pandas, split

I have a dataframe, which containes a column with a string. it looks like :

```
[a]
aaa aa a aaaa
bbb bbb b
cc cccc ccc cc ccc
```

What I would like is to add 6 columns with spliting values of [a], like this :

```
[a]                     [a0]    [a1]    [a2]    [a3]    [a4]    [a5]
aaa aa a aaaa           aaa     aa      a       aaaa    NaN     NaN
bbb bbb b               bbb     bbb     b       NaN     NaN     NaN
cc cccc ccc cc ccc      cc      cccc    ccc     cc      ccc     NaN
```

I use this code :

```
for i in range(6):
     df["a{}".format(i)] = df[a].apply(lambda x:x.split(' ')[i])
```

but I have a 'out of range' error, which can be explain because all values have not the same number element.

How I can avoid this error, and replace all values in error by None ?

Thanks in advance.
BR,

EDIT : we never know in advance the length of string to split. Something it contains 2 occurences, sometimes 4, etc..

Comment: Do you know the number of columns in advance? And if not, is it costly to scan the dataframe once to get it?

Comment: Hi IanS. No we don't know, but we suppose that the number will never be more than 6 columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there :) 
All you have to do is to add the following small condition at the end of your current lambda function:

```
if len(x.split(" "))>i else None
```

Your code becomes:

```
for i in range(6):
     df["a{}".format(i)] = df[a].apply(lambda x: x.split(' ')[i] if len(x.split(' ')>i else None)
```

Comment: Hi mircealungu. As you say, I'm almost there :)
if fact, on your code (still out of range error), I finally change to :

    for i in range(6):
         df["a{}".format(i)] = df[a].apply(lambda x: x.split(' ')[i] if len(x.split(' '))>i else None).

More simply like this, I like :) Thanks.
BR

Answer (score 8):

You could use `str.split` and provide `expand=True` so that it enlarges into a dataframe for each of those individual splits.

Reindex these by providing an added range so that we can create an extra column with `NaNs`. Provide an optional prefix char later.

Then, concatentate the original and the extracted `DF's` column-wise.

```
str_df = df['a'].str.split(expand=True).reindex(columns=np.arange(6)).add_prefix('a')
pd.concat([df, str_df], axis=1).replace({None:np.NaN})
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Nickil. Thanks again, it worked.